# Configuration Options in .net core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

How do lambda `Options` work with `services.Add*` in .NET Core?

I usually do the following with `services.Configure`,

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(
  Configuration.GetSection("my-option-section-in-appsettings.json"));
```

or lambda variant,

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(options =>
{
     options.PropertyName = "some-thing"
}
```

But when it comes to the following, I'm lost,

```
services.AddMyService(options => options.UseMethod1(...));
```

I tried traversing the code where the above is used, but i fail to find my way through. The quickest example I can get is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Startup.cs#L39-L40)

Comment: I dont think this will be possible, since the configuration service is for holding information. I would suggest implementing just a simple service... like it was done in the services folder in the same link: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Services

Comment: I don't get why you say it's not possible, while the link i provided clearly include this `options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))`

Comment: You are asking to invoke a method in the Configuration, have a closer look at your link. In your example there is a method call in the in the Lambda of UseSqlServer which is NOT the Configuration...

Comment: There is no where i'm invoking a method on `Configuration`. I'm not sure you are getting the question right.

Comment: Unless you mean `Configuration.GetSection("my-option-section-in-appsettings.json")` or the title is confusing? the method i invoke is `options.UseMethod1())` which has nothing to do with `Configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

> How do lambda `Options` work with `services.Add*` in **.NET Core**?

The common pattern is to add an expression that satisfies the `Action<TOptions>` delegate. The `TOptions` is the object that corresponds to the add function, that gives you the consumer an opportunity to update the object, setting values or invoking methods as you see fit. The `Action<TOptions>` is executed as part of the service's lifetime. For example when adding MVC with the [`.AddMvc`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L80) extension method the framework will invoke your action prior to the service being available to for consumption. So with this specific example, all of the underlying MVC services are registered and an options object is instantiated and given to you to act on.

Comment: This gives a light. I think I'm getting lost on the `builder` call graph. One builder passing a call to another builder which passes the call to another.

Comment: This part of the beauty of the design. The ability to allow consumers to express alterations via an options object, captured in a `Action<TOptions>` delegate.

Comment: What if you don't want to update the object? Should you add empty lambdas for every IOptions which is registered? I can't seem to find a better solution.